# Using queue Between two object of class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++17

In order to send messages between two objects of class!
I implemeted this

```
class User
{
public:

    
    
     virtual void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string receivedMessage = receiveMessage();
            sendMessage(receivedMessage);
        }
    }

    
     virtual void sendMessage(string message)
    {
        sentQueue.push(reply);
    };

    
     virtual string receiveMessage()
    {
        string receivedMessage;
        receivedMessage = receivedQueue.pop();
        return receivedMessage;
    };
private:
    
};
```

What I am asking now is where to instantiate this blocking queue to use it between the two objects (User 1 and User 2) in order to exchange messages between them

Comment: Not bad, but take a look at how `wait` is used in the example at the bottom of [this documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). It's a little bit cleaner.

Comment: `T value(std::move(this->queue_.pop()));` isn't quite right. `std::queue::pop` doesn't return anything. Probably should be `T value(std::move(this->queue_.front()));`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Instead of what i wrote  i will change it to  :  this->cv_.wait(lck_, [=] { return !this->queue.empty(); });   .  Thanks a lot

Comment: pm100's answer addresses that. Each `Player` should have its own `BlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a global send queue and a global receive queue. What you need is a receive queue per player.

Have a send method on the player class that writes to their send queue

So player 1 would go

```
  player2.Send("hello player2");
```

---

How to do it

```
class Player
{
     BlockingQueue<string> queue_ = BlockingQueue<string>();
public:

     void Post(const string& message){
         queue_.push(message);
     }

 
virtual void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string msg= queue_.pop();
         // do something with the message
        if(msg == "BangBang")
        { 
        }
    }
}
```

now you can go

```
Player player1("player1");
Player player2("player2");
thread thread1(&Player::run, player1);
thread thread2(&Player::run, player2);

player1.Post("BangBang");
```

Probably you should make you message more that a string, something like

```
 class Message{
     Player* sender;
     string text;
     CommandType ct;
  }
```

or have a string syntax like "player1/shoot/0,5"

you need to know who the message cam from so you can react correctly and maybe reply

---

or maybe the post method is called on the sending player object and includes the destination user. Using my suggested Message class

```
class Player
{
     BlockingQueue<Message> queue_ = BlockingQueue<Message>();
public:

     void Post(const string& message, Player *dest){
         Message msg;
         msg.sender= this; // sender 
         msg.text = message;
         dest->queue_.push(message);
     }
 
virtual void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Message msg= queue_.pop();
         // do something with the message
        if(msg.Text == "BangBang")
        { 
              /// check for hit
             // reply to sender
            Post("you got me", msg.sender);
        }
    }
}
```

now

```
 Player player1("player1");
 Player player2("player2");
 thread thread1(&Player::run, player1);
 thread thread2(&Player::run, player2);

  player2.Post("BangBang", &player1); // send message to player2 (from 1)
```

Comment: Do you mean, that instead of  having a global send queue and a global receive queue, i just need to have receive and send queue per player? sorry  maybe i did't get you ! can you please explain

Comment: @Ben Think about how you would use a global queue. Would both players be blocked on reading messages from it? What would player1 do if it read its own messages? Put them back in the queue and hope it didn't read them again next time?

Comment: @Ben - a queue per player. When you want to send a message to a player write to their queue. No send or receive queues, the per player queue is receive as far as the owning player is concerned, and send queue as far as the sender is concerned,

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation I get it now! What if changing the size of my globals queue to 1 where it will accept 1 message as maximum!  will it work also?

Comment: @Ben - see edit, many many possibilities

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir ! But one thing, in this example that you implemented how can player1 send the message to player2 and player 2 reply to him?  From what i see in your example, each player can write only to his queue but how can each of them access to the other player's queue? Since the blocking queue will be re-created with every object of the class Player

Comment: @Ben Each player needs to know the other players. For two players, this is a nice and simple, they hold a reference to the other player, but it doesn't really scale all that well beyond two. If you have many players, you should consider a message broker that knows all of the players and all of the players merely know the message broker. They send a message to the broker along with information the broker uses to identify the recipient. The broker places the message in the recipient's queue.

Comment: @Ben player1.Post posts to player1's queue, Player2 code can call that, if ppayer1 wants to reply to player2 they go player2.Post. I suggest that the message contains somewy of ideentifying the sender (a unique string that can be looked up in a map or a pointer to the sending Player object, hence the stucture of the proposed Message object)

Comment: @Ben - i will edit in mode suggestions

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, pm! It means a lot to me! One last thing, sir, when creating the class Message, remember to include `Player* sender` as a field! I'm concerned that it will create another blockingQueue and then raise an error stating that a blocking has already been defined.

Comment: @Ben - I did include Player*sender in Message

Comment: Yes sir , what i mean when you did include Player*sender in Message , it will raise an error stating that the blocking queue has already been defined !

Comment: @Ben - nope - thats becuase you do not have include guards, or becuase you still have the global queues in a header somewhere (or both). It is perfectly fine to include Player*sender in message class

Comment: Yes that's true sir ! sorry for that ! But it seems that the blocking queue that i implemented doesnt support the class Message as valid template type argument for parameter T .   `Message is not a valid template type argument for parameter T`

Comment: @Ben, you get that error becuase you did not declared Message before you tried to use it as type arg for BlockingQueue. You need to put Message declaration in message.h and include that in player.h

Comment: That's true Sir, One last thing please, in the class Message, `Player* sender` , it said that `sender` is not a member of Message and it's not recognizing it  even in Player class .

Comment: @Ben - I suggest you post a new question with your newest code, its hard for me to imagine the mistakes you are making

Comment: @LouisGo - good catch, as you can see OP and I iterated a lot on this code

Comment: Hello pm100 ! one thing i want to say ! in this case and with your solution ! we don't need a the implemented blocking queue anymore ! we can just use a the standard std::queue ! and it will work smoothly

Comment: @Ben - you sure? Your 'run' thread will be looping at 100% cpu

Comment: you're right sir!